# N-tier Application Data Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

I develop a ntier MVC application with .NET. I have four layer. 
UI layer, ServiceLayer, Business Layer and DAL. (I use EF5 for DAL)

I add a project for my Entities. My projects structure as this.

```
MyProject.DAL
MyProject.Interfaces
MyProject.Entities
MyProject.MvcWebUI
MyProject.BLL
```

I wonder that, i need sometimes strongly type class model for method's return. But it's not neccessary store in database. Shortly it's not an entity.

For example i have Product entity. But i need a model it's store Product's status and count. How should locate it?

```
public enum ProdReviewResult
{
    Accepted = 1,
    Declined = 2,
    Banned = 4
}

//MyProject.DAL
//I need here return to strongly typed model
public List<object> GetProdReviewStatusByProdGroup(int userId, int prodGroupId)
{
    var query = from p in _db.Products
        join pg in _db.ProdGroups on p.ProdGroupId equals pg.ProdGroupId
        where pg.UserId == userId && p.UserId == userId
        group p by p
        into g
        select new {ProdViewResult = g.Key, ProdCount = g.Count()};

    var reviewStatus = new List<object>();
    foreach (var result in query)
    {
        reviewStatus.Add(new {result.ProdViewResult, result.ProdCount});
    }

    return reviewStatus;
}

//This class model for products to group by ProdReviewStatus.
//How should i locate in my project. 
public ProdReviewCount()
{
    public ProdReviewStatus ProdReviewStatus{get;set;}
    public int Count{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have intimate knowledge of your application, but this seems excessive to me. A service layer, business layer and DAL are pretty much all the same thing. They're all part of the domain. Unless you have a really good reason not discussed here why you need all three as distinct projects, I'd say you should look into trying to merge some of this where appropriate.

That said, what you're talking about is just a DTO (data transfer object). As such, based on your current structure, I'd say it should go with your DAL project.

Comment: I 'u use my service layer(MyProject.Interfaces) for mobile application .I'll host it on IIS.  And i use BLL for various business operation.

Comment: I'd agree with Chris Pratt although I might keep the DAL as a separate project. Didn't N-Teir going out of fashion years ago?!